# The Sneaky Sly Horse Trader

Tags: logical-deduction

Once upon a time, there was a horse trader. One morning, the horse trader bought a horse for \$60. Just after noon, the horse trader sold the same horse back to their original owner for \$70. He then bought it back again just before 5PM for \$80. By midnight he managed to sell the horse back to the original owner for \$90. How much money did the horse trader make or lose on his horse?

Comment: trader didn't make any profits or lose anything..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove that this man has a profit of 20 and not 10?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61006/how-to-prove-that-this-man-has-a-profit-of-20-and-not-10)

Answer (score 1):

The horse trader made:

> \$20.

Reasoning:

> Let us assume HT started the day with \$100. After the first trade, HT has a horse and \$40. After the second trade, HT has \$110. After the third, HT has \$30 and a horse. After the fourth, HT has \$120. HT is \$20 up.

Answer (score 0):

I think he made

> a $20 profits

I try a different approach from @JonMark Perry's answer:

> You can separate all purchases into two disjoint purchase. So at first, he bought \$60 and sold \$70, he made \$10. Next, he bought \$80 and sold \$90, so he made \$10 again, so the total is \$20